# How to edit Global Address List office 365 using c#

Tags: c#, outlook, ldap, exchange-server

This is my code to edit GAL, I get error

> Message=You do not have sufficient permission to perform this
>   operation on this object.   Source=Microsoft Outlook.

not possible to edit via outlook api am admin user ?

```
Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application( );

Outlook.AddressEntry dlEntry = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").AddressLists["Global Address List"].AddressEntries["Global Employees"];
Outlook.AddressEntries members = dlEntry.Members;


foreach (Outlook.AddressEntry member in members)
{
    MessageBox.Show(member.Name + ":" + member.Address + ":" + member.GetExchangeUser().JobTitle);
    member.Name =  member.Name  + " Edited";
    member.GetExchangeUser().JobTitle = member.GetExchangeUser().JobTitle  + " Edited";;
    member.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The GAL (Global Address List) is generated from Active Directory Elements. Therefore you need to edit the unterlaying active directory and not directly the GAL. In your case with Exchange Online (part from Office 365) it is the underlaying Azure Active Directory.

*If you use DirSync / Azure AD Connect you can also update the content inside your on premises Active Directory environment so that it is synced with Azure Active Directory.*

Comment: ok . could you please give me any sample code for editing office365 active directory ? and i dont understand why these is a method for update() and create () in  Outlook.Application api